Blonde corporal in G.I. Joe: The Rise of Cobra?
There's a blonde corporal in 2009's G.I. Joe movie, who gets slaughtered during the raid on The Pit.
What is her role name and what her real name?
I'm really not sure, but this might be her ("Cover Girl"?):

Additional questions:
She didn't survive and re-appear in one of the sequels, did she?
Is it the same in the comics?

That is indeed Cover Girl played by Karolína Kurková, she did die in the movie and has not appeared since.
In the various comics continuities (and cartoons) the character Cover Girl does not die.

This is too sad, she didn't deserve to die :( Thanks for the info!
